# If I store an object in a PHP session, when I retrieve this object, is it a fully fledged object that I can call functions on?

Tags: php

I have an object, and I am using php's session to persist the objects state.  Here is basically what I'm doing:

I have "object A" which contains one "object B".  In the constructor for A, I am simply grabbing B from the session and setting "object B" equal to its appropriate value in the session.

I then proceed to call some of object b's functions, but I have a feeling this may be wrong.

Do objects stored and retrieved from a php session retain their capabilities, or do they become data storage objects with no capabilities?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects will be serialized before being placed in the session, thus they will be "fully fledged" when they are retrieved form the session due to de-serialization. Note that the object's class needs to be available at the time of deserialization.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php

Comment: For custom classes, you may want to checkout the `__sleep` and `__wakeup` magic methods. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep