# how to get a class value from session variable

Tags: php, class, loops, oop

```
<?php
class Profile{

     var $customer_id;
     var $first_name;
     var $last_name;
     var $company_name;
     var $email;
     var $password;
     var $address;
     var $place;
     var $pin;
     var $state;
     var $mobile;
     var $phone;
     var $fax;
     var $created_date;
     var $modify_date;
     var $status;
     var $loginStatus;
     var $error;


            public static function loginCheck($DB,$emailId,$password)
            {
                    $instance = new self();
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = '$emailId' and password=md5('$password')";

                    $rs=mysqli_query($DB, $query);
                    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($rs);
                    $find=mysqli_num_rows($rs);

                        if($find==1)
                        {
                             $instance->customer_id=$row['customer_id'];
                             $instance->first_name=$row['first_name'];
                             $instance->last_name=$row['last_name'];
                             $instance->company_name=$row['company_name'];
                             $instance->email=$row['email'];
                             $instance->password=$row['password'];
                             $instance->address=$row['address'];
                             $instance->place=$row['place'];
                             $instance->pin=$row['pin'];
                             $instance->state=$row['state'];
                             $instance->mobile=$row['mobile'];
                             $instance->phone=$row['phone'];
                             $instance->fax=$row['fax'];
                             $instance->created_date=$row['created_date'];
                             $instance->modify_date=$row['modify_date'];
                             $instance->status=$row['status'];

                                 if($row['status']="Active")
                                 {
                                    $instance->loginStatus=true;
                                    $instance->error=""; 

                                 }
                                 else
                                 {
                                     $instance->loginStatus=false;
                                     $instance->error="User is not an Active Please Activate it."; 

                                 }
                        }
                        else
                        {

                        $instance->loginStatus=false;
                        $instance->error="User Name / Password Invalid .";  
                        }

                    return $instance;
                    }



}
?>
```

and use this class and get the value properly. i want to  store this object into a SESSION variable for global sharing. how to get back the object value 
from.
in my code the following line is used to get  the value and sore it in session variable

```
$log= Profile::loginCheck($con,$username,$pass);
$_SESSION['Profile']=$log;
```

in another  page i use this code for get from session vaiable

```
$login=$_SESSION['Profile'];
```

here i use this code to get value

```
$login->first_name
```

but return nothing. suppose if i use

```
print_r($login)
```

it display all value. how i get the value

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Forgive me but I see no logic in putting a class instance in a session... There's must be a better approach to achieve your goal.

Comment: i want to get all login information in every page. so i use  session variable

Comment: Why not storing just a hash of the user's id in the session and have a function that retrieves that data from the DB? And then basically, just run this function on every page.

Comment: every time it will get it from db. so i want to avoid that .

Comment: 1. Using a single query for that purpose isn't a "waste" - it's a fundamental usage of a query in any members-related system.
2. You can use some caching methods for efficient results.
3. However, You still can store some data you know you'd to need to use - simply serialize it the object.

Comment: ok. thanks. for your help

Comment: Yea - take a look: http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: serialize($log); method not working. any other method.pls

Comment: in my object it have all the data. my problem is how to get  a particulate data from the object. for the code $login=$_SESSION['Profile']; it return all the value. but i am unable to get the particulat data value eg. $login->first_name

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9077723/if-i-store-an-object-in-a-php-session-when-i-retrieve-this-object-is-it-a-full

Comment: Have you investigated your error log files? There should be an answer on what is happening while php is processing what's stored within session.

Comment: thanks all i got the solution. using $_SESSION['Profile']=serialize($log); and $login=unserialize($_SESSION['Profile']);. before unserialize we must include the class file.. thanks once again

Comment: @Ravindr answer your own question with the solution. This is important for other users that might have the same problem.